# How do I start SourceTree 2 from the command line on Windows?

Tags: powershell, atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree 2.0 is substantially different from SourceTree 1 in that it uses a rolling release model - eg:

```
$ ls $env:LOCALAPPDATA\sourcetree


    Directory: C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\sourcetree


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       27/04/2017     17:12                app-2.0.19.1
d-----       09/05/2017     10:44                app-2.0.20.1
d-----       09/05/2017     10:44                packages
-a----       08/05/2017     16:25           3225 SquirrelSetup.log
-a----       18/04/2017     23:51        1518408 Update.exe
```

So there's no static directory for SourceTree executables anymore.

Previous versions of SourceTree included [an 'stree' command](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Questions/How-do-I-use-Command-Line-Tools/qaq-p/190043) but the 'Install Command Line Tools' option but this is [MacOS only](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/SourceTree-command-line-option/qaq-p/53287).

**How do I start SourceTree 2 from the command line on Windows?**

Comment: The support thread you linked mentions where to find the location of the current version of the executable: `Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\sourcetree\shell\open\command`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yep working on that now. Hopefully I can find an answer if someone else doesn't first.

Answer (score 2):

Got it. As Steve Streeting mentions here you can get the [current path the active version of SourceTree 2 from the registry](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/SourceTree-command-line-option/qaq-p/53287).

Combining that with some powershell gives:

```
function stree {
    $SourceTreeCommand = (Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Classes\sourcetree\shell\open\command).'(default)'.split()[0].replace('"','')
    & $SourceTreeCommand -f .
}
```